# C# - string.Compare with char '-' has a weird behavior

Tags: c#

```
int i;
i = String.Compare("A-", "A0"); // i = -1 -> OK
i = String.Compare("A-A", "A0A"); // i = 1 -> WHY ?
```

I don't understand why appending the SAME letter 'A' to both text can change the value returned ?

I know String.CompareOrdinal will return the correct negative value in both cases. I would like to know why String.Compare doesn't.

Comment: you might find [this bit of documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/best-practices-strings#the-details-of-string-comparison) useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put, the hyphen is being ignored. The following would yield the same results

```
var ads = new[] {"A", "A0", "AA", "A0A"};
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",ads.OrderBy(x => x)));
```

---

[String.Compare Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compare?view=netcore-3.1)

**Notes to Callers**

> Character sets include ignorable characters. The
> Compare(String, String) method does not consider such characters when
> it performs a culture-sensitive comparison. For example, if the
> following code is run on the .NET Framework 4 or later, a
> culture-sensitive comparison of "animal" with "ani-mal" (using a soft
> hyphen, or U+00AD) indicates that the two strings are equivalen

**Further more**

> To recognize ignorable characters in a string comparison, call the
> Compare(String, String, StringComparison) method and supply a value of
> either Ordinal or OrdinalIgnoreCase for the comparisonType parameter.